# Pdf calculation

Tags: probability

I have obtained a pdf for

```
                  G= variable1 -variable2
```

The pdf for this comes out to be a triangle, which is given by

```
                  fG(g)=g+1              for   0<g<-1
                  fG(g)=1-g              for   0<=g<1
```

Now , I want to find out the pdf for G^2,So I have to find out

```
                       Y=G^2
```

which can be calculated using this formula

$g(y)=G'(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}(f(\sqrt{y})+f(-\sqrt{y}))$

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/263943/53984
                    But the main problem is when I put g+1 in the above formula for the specific range from 0 to 1  .The pdf is somehow not coming correct.Please help me out in this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $$g(y) =  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}(f(\sqrt{y})+f(-\sqrt{y}))$$ for $0 \le y \le 1$ then you can use your earlier expression for $f(x)$ to produce

$$g(y) =  \frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}((1-\sqrt{y})+(1-\sqrt{y})) = \frac{1-\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{y}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}-1.$$

Comment: The sign of second f(x) will be reversed in the above equation resulting in 1/(y^0.5).Am I right?

Comment: Since $(-\sqrt{y}) \le 0$ you have $f(-\sqrt{y}) = 1 + (-\sqrt{y}) = 1 -\sqrt{y}$

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting it.Actually for this specific range of y.The pdf is 1-(y)^0.5.The second term of pdf will be (1-(-y^0.5)).Please explain your logic..

Comment: When $0 \le y \le 1$ you have $-1 \le -\sqrt{y}\le 0$.  You know that the original density for $-1 \le x \le 0$ is $f(x)=1+x$ so letting $x=-\sqrt{y}$ that becomes $f(-\sqrt{y})= 1 +(-\sqrt{y})$.

Answer (score 1):

You had reached the stage
$$g(y)=G'(y)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}(f_G(\sqrt{y})+f_G(-\sqrt{y})).$$
So all that needs to be done is to evaluate (i) $f_G(\sqrt{y})$ and (ii) $f_G(-\sqrt{y})$.

For (i), $\sqrt{y}$ is non-negative, so we look up the formula for $f_G(g)$ when $g\ge 0$, and substitute $\sqrt{y}$ wherever we see $g$. We get $1-\sqrt{y}$.

For (ii), note that $-\sqrt{y}$ is $\le 0$. So we look up the formula for $f_G(g0$ in that case. For $-1\le g\le 0$ we have $f_G(b)=g+1$. Substitute $-\sqrt{y}$ for $g$. We get $-\sqrt{y}+1$. Finally, add and simplify.

**Remark:** We can use the geometry to avoid the unpleasantness of negative values of $G$. The density function of $G$ is **symmetric**. Let $0\le y\le 1$. We have $Y\le y$ if and only if $|G|\le \sqrt{y}$. By symmetry, 
$$\Pr(|G|\le \sqrt{y})=2\Pr(0\le G\le \sqrt{y}).$$
Now we can work purely with non-negative values of $G$.